# Unable to write xpath for a perticular link in the browser

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have a link in my application for which i need to write a script in pycharm please find the absolute xpath for the link as below:

HTML Script:

```
<div id="gwt-uid-71" class="gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH">FINDINGS</div>
```

and the Script:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//div [contains(@class,'gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH') and text()[contains(.,'FINDINGS')]]
Click Element    xpath=//div [contains(@class,'gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH') and text()[contains(.,'FINDINGS')]]
```

but when i execute the above script i am getting the following error:

> Message:  StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer
>   attached to the DOM Stacktrace:
>       at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9351)
>       at Utils.getElementAt (file:///c:/users/nav/appdata/local/temp/tmpnvucai/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8942)
>       at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/nav/appdata/local/temp/tmpnvucai/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9980)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///c:/users/nav/appdata/local/temp/tmpnvucai/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12626)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/nav/appdata/local/temp/tmpnvucai/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12643)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/nav/appdata/local/temp/tmpnvucai/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12648)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/nav/appdata/local/temp/tmpnvucai/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12590)

Comment: We cannot make it out from the absolute xpath, give us the html snippet for which you wrote the script.

Comment: Please provide the HTML of the element you want to click (we don't want the full page HTML)

Comment: <div>
<div class="GCBQC1SDHLH">
<div class="GCBQC1SDELH" tabindex="0">
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"/>
<div id="Findings-1438332543894" class="GCBQC1SDFLH">
<div class="GCBQC1SDILH">
<div id="gwt-uid-71" class="gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH">FINDINGS</div>
<div class="GCBQC1SDCLH"/>
</div>
<div class="gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDDLH">(361)</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: This is the exact xpath link:                                                                       <div id="gwt-uid-71" class="gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH">FINDINGS</div> <div class="GCBQC1SDCLH"/>

Answer (score 0):

Is the class generic or static? Does it change? Because as you said you want to find

```
<div id="gwt-uid-71" class="gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH">FINDINGS</div> <div class="GCBQC1SDCLH"/>
```

this do not match your posted xpath

```
.//*[@class='gwt-Label GP5LRU5DCNH GP5LRU5DNMH'][text()='FINDINGS']
```

because the class is different.

If the class is always the same, the correct xpath would be:

```
//div [contains(@class,'gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH') and text()[contains(.,'FINDINGS')]]
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It is identifying but when i run the script its showing the error below:\

Comment: Can you show us more of your code/script? This should actually work

Comment: It is identifying but when i run the script its showing the error :@class,'gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH') and text()[contains(.,'FINDINGS'] did not appear in 5 seconds even though i have given a wait statement.

Comment: This is my script:                                                                                  Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=.//*[@class='gwt-Label GP5LRU5DCNH GP5LRU5DNMH'][text()='FINDINGS']
    Click Element    xpath=//div [contains(@class,'gwt-Label GCBQC1SDGLH GCBQC1SDBLH') and text()[contains(.,'FINDINGS')]]

Comment: That is strange because I can't find the problem (I think you also replaced your `wait until page contains element` xpath with mine and only did a typo). Maybe if you edit your post and enter more details about the complete HTML code and more of your script.

Comment: I have edited the original question,could you please help me,i have added the html script,xpath and my scipt